# Could one be a friend of all?

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

The social network "ILM" has a lot of members. It is well known: If you choose any 4 members of the network, then one of these 4 members is a friend of the other 3.

> <strike>Proof:</strike> Is then among any 4 members always one who is a friend of all
>   members of the social network "ILM"?

*Note:* If member A is a friend of member B then member B is also a friend of member A.

I don't find an approach right now. Any kind of help or advice will be really appreciated.

Comment: The word "proof" seems out of place.

Comment: You are definitely right. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $P$ be the set of members. For $p,q\in P$ I’ll write $p\sim q$ to indicate that $p$ and $q$ are friends, and $p\not\sim q$ to indicate that they are not.

Suppose first that there are three people, $p,q$, and $r$, such that $p\not\sim q$ and $p\not\sim r$.

- Show that if $s\in P\setminus\{p,q,r\}$, then $s\sim p$, $s\sim q$, and $s\sim r$.
- Then show that if $s,t\in P\setminus\{p,q,r\}$, and $s\ne t$, then $s\sim t$.
- Conclude that among any four members of $P$ there is always at least one who is friends with every other member of $P$.

Now suppose that if $S$ is any $3$-member subset of $P$, then there is at least one $p\in S$ who is friends with both other members of $S$. Suppose further that $p$ and $q$ are two members of $P$ who are not friends.

- Argue very much as in the first case to show that every member of $P\setminus\{p,q\}$ is friends with every other member of $P$.

Comment: Thank you! But how can i show show that if s,t∈P∖{p,q,r}, and s≠t, then s∼t and how can i conclude that among any four members of P there is always at least one who is friends with every other member of P? 

I am sorry for my lack of knowledge, I am still in highschool.

Comment: @Fullbright: Look at the foursome $\{p,q,s,t\}$; someone in it has to be friends with all three of the others, and it can’t be $p$ or $q$ (why?), so it must be $s$ or $t$. But then $s$ and $t$ are friends.

Comment: Now I understand, it can’t be p or q because I supposed that they are not friends at the beginning.

Comment: @Fullbright: That’s right. And the same kind of reasoning should get you through the other case as well.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do you think what I wrote makes sense?

Comment: At the end of your answer, you look at an analogous result for when in any group of three people there’s someone who knows the other two. However, I don’t believe that argument works. For example, consider a cycle of four people. Then in any three it’s true that one knows the other two, but it’s not the case that one person knows everyone else. Perhaps I’m missing something?

Comment: @templatetypedef: That’s not looking at an analogous result: it’s completing the proof of the result in the original question. The part that begins *Suppose first* deals only with the case in which there are $p,q$, and $r$ such that $p\not\sim q$ and $p\not\sim r$. To complete the proof, you still have to deal with the possibility that there is no such trio. In that case you can prove that in every trio there is someone who is friends with both of the others. Now you use that assumption together with the fact that in each foursome there is someone who is friends with the other three.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @templatetypedef: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there isn't a person who knows everyone.

Then take vertex $v$, he doesn't know everyone, in particular there is a $w$ he does not know.

If $w$ doesn't know anybody we are done, if he does select a friend of $w$, Preferably somebody who does not know somebody besides $v$ (if everybody that knows $w$ knows everybody except possibly $v$ you can argue that everybody who knows $w$ does not know $v$, hence you can pick any other two vertices and there will be no one knowing all three). So suppose there is a friend of $w$ called $u$ that does not know someone else called $t$. In the group $v,w,u,t$ there is no one who knows the rest.